# vue-jest related: Cannot find module 'vue' from

Tags: jestjs, vue-jest

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pcg6e.png)

As it shows in the picture, I have two projects that share some vue components.
I import ImageBlock.vue in my Card.vue component, it works fine. But when I write test cases for Card component, I got the error

```
> Cannot find module 'vue' from '../sharedComponents/ImageBlock.vue'
```

I searched, couldn't find any answers. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the path from your test directory is wrong.
If your test is in `project2/test`,

you should try importing from `../../sharedComponents/ImageBlock.vue`

Comment: The path is not the problem. That component is imported correctly, and I don't need to import it in the test file. It's something else.